# Alerts triggering without condition met - can you help? pinescript help needed

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

First, I want to say that I am a total layman so you'll need to help me like I'm writing in crayon lmao.

That being said, I have tried to add alerts to an indicator that previously didn't have them.  I have managed to get them into the alert tool, in the capacity that I want. however, the alert is meant to be triggered when the correlated label (either ^ or v) prints on the chart and when I create the alert (regardless of tool setting) it is sending an alert, essentially without condition, basically on every bar close if that was selected setting.

I followed a similar question and answer, instructing to use flags to accomplish this. But, it is not working as intended.   I assume this is possibly because the flag is triggering based on the if function that proceeds it and there may be some coding I don't fully understand in the "label.new" function line that gives it more logic before printing the actual label?

this is as close as i've gotten and I have previously tried using the labels themselves, or the if logic itself as the qualifier for the alert condition function.  I've included a photo of the code, but also included copy paste below.

UPDATES:

1. as suggested, I have tried to define the flags as var variables.  this did not change the effect of the alerts at all, unfortunately.
2. i have been trying to extract the drawing logic and alerts from the "loop" as suggested.  but, I'm afraid my ignorance may be limiting my ability to follow instructions. i have tried the alerts in local and global scope.  still cant get it.
   .....................................................

   ```
   h = input(8.,'Bandwidth')
    src = input(close,'Source')
    //----
    n = bar_index
    var ln = array.new_line(0) 
    var LONG = false
    var SHORT = false
    if barstate.isfirst
        for i = 0 to 499
            array.push(ln,line.new(na,na,na,na))
    //----
    float y2 = na
    float y1 = na
    float y1_d = na
    //----
    line l = na
    label lb = na
    if barstate.islast
        for i = 0 to min(499,n-1)
            sum = 0.
            sumw = 0.
            for j = 0 to min(499,n-1)
                w = exp(-(pow(i-j,2)/(h*h*2)))
                sum += src[j]*w
                sumw += w
            y2 := sum/sumw
            d = y2 - y1

            l := array.get(ln,i)
            line.set_xy1(l,n-i+1,y1)
            line.set_xy2(l,n-i,y2)
            line.set_color(l,y2 > y1 ? #ff1100 : #39ff14)
            line.set_width(l,2)

            if d > 0 and y1_d < 0
                label.new(n i+1,src[i],'▲',color=#00000000,style=label.style_label_up,textcolor=#39ff14,textalign=text.align_center)
                LONG := true
            if d < 0 and y1_d > 0
                SHORT := true
                label.new(n-i+1,src[i],'▼',color=#00000000,style=label.style_label_down,textcolor=#ff1100,textalign=text.align_center)
            y1 := y2
            y1_d := d
    //--------- ALERTING 


    alertcondition(LONG,  title='BUY', message='LONG {{ticker}} TIMEFRAME {{interval}}')
    LONG := false //reset flag
    alertcondition(SHORT, title='Sell', message='SHORT {{ticker}} TIMEFRAME {{interval}}') 
    SHORT := false //reset flag
   ```

Comment: Try to define `LONG` and `SHORT` as `var` variables. 
`var LONG = false`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!  Unfortunately, that didn't work.  Was I supposed to add anything other than defining them as Vars?  no need to modify the alerts?  it just triggers on every bar, even when the label isn't triggered. same problem as before

Comment: Problems seems to be that you do all operations inside a loop and on a ticking bar. Inside this loop `long` and `short` conditions is changing multiple times. 
This is what actually happens with your `label` if you draw it with different y-coordinates: https://pasteboard.co/bJD0JIjxaxUf.png
You need to extract your drawing logic and alerting from the loop.

Comment: Can you explain that more?  or maybe there is a writeup somewhere on that, that you can point me to?  I have been trying to remove it, but, I'm afraid my ignorance may be limiting me lol